# How many ambiguous combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

I am not a mathematician so please forgive my ignorance.

I am examining a body of data in which animals are identified by marking their toes. These animals have four feet, with differing number of markable toes per foot depending on morphology.

Each mark is ascribed an integer value for its position (i.e., the first toe counts X, the second toe counts Y, the third toe counts Z, and so on) such that the sum of the values of all marked toes on an animal is the identity number of the individual.

Various numbering schemes are used. In the case I am currently looking at the values given to the four sets (one set per foot) of marks are: {70000, 1, 2, 4, 7}, {40000, 10, 20, 40, 70}, {20000, 100, 200, 400, 700} and {10000, 1000, 2000, 4000, 7000}.

I believe I can calculate the number of possible combinations of marks $\binom{A}{B}$ where A is the number of toes per foot that could be marked, and B is the number of toes per foot that are marked.

So, for example, marking up to two (0, 1 or 2) of five toes per foot produces $(\binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2})^4 -1 = 65,534$ possible combinations of marks (with the $-1$ eliminating the completely unmarked combination).

However, the numbering scheme shown above (and other schemes) can produce ambiguous identity numbers where more than one combination of marks can produce the same identity number. I.e., (trivially) the marks 4+7 and marks 1+10 both sum to 11.

I have two questions:

1. How can I calculate the number of ambiguous combinations of marks for a given $\binom{A}{B}$ and numbering scheme?
2. Without resorting to exhaustive iteration, is it possible to determine whether an arbitrary identity number (sum of marks) is ambiguous or unique?

Any guidance much appreciated!

p.s. I tagged this question with "combinatronics"; please advise if other tags would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why not just do an exhaustive iteration? There is only about a million possibilities afterall.

Comment: Thanks @Jens.  Yes, I can do that, but as I mentioned I have described just one case. I ultimately need to consider various $\binom{A}{B}$ and various numbering schemes. So I could make these inputs into a software algorithm, but a straight forward mathematical solution would likely be a more elegant.

Comment: Given the screw... uh...."unconventional" nature of these ID schemes, I seriously doubt any elegant mathematical solution exists.

Comment: I agree the numbering scheme is "unconventional". So what if we arrange the existing four physical sets: {70000, 1, 2, 4, 7}, {40000, 10, 20, 40, 70}, {20000, 100, 200, 400, 700} and {10000, 1000, 2000, 4000, 7000} into five _logical_ sets: {1, 2, 4, 7}, {10, 20, 40, 70}, {100, 200, 400, 700}, {1000, 2000, 4000, 7000},  and {10000, 20000, 40000, 70000}? With this arrangement ambiguity exists for any combination of marks within a set whose value is $>=$ an element of the next set.

Comment: Following my own logic, there are no combinations of $\binom{4}{0}$ or $\binom{4}{1}$ that satisfy the condition for ambiguity. There is one ambiguous combination of $\binom{4}{2}$ which is $4+7 >= 10$, and there are three ambiguous combinations of $\binom{4}{3}$ which are $1+2+7 >= 10$, $1+4+7 >= 10$, and $2+4+7 >= 10$. I can subtract these from the numbers of unambiguous combinations to derive the total number of ambiguous combinations.

Comment: Just made a program to run through all combinations. There are $1,048,576$ combinations of markings, but given the numbering scheme we know the largest possible number is $155,554$. Of these, there are only $4,433$ which are unique.

Comment: @Jens how do you get 1,048,576 combinations?  Ignoring ambiguous combinations there are $(\binom{5}{0}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2})^4-1$ ways I can mark 0, 1, or 2 toes on each of four (five-toed) feet. This yields $(1 + 5 + 10)^4 -1 = 65,535$ combinations.

Comment: The million comes from all combinations of marking between $0$ and $20$ toes, i.e. $2^{20}$. Are you saying at most $2$ toes may be marked per foot?

Comment: Modified my program so at most $2$ toes per foot can be marked. This gives $52,150$ different sums, of which $10,819$ are ambiguous. So limiting the number of toes that can be marked actually gives many more unique sums.

Comment: @Jens could you post your code/pseudo code as an answer so I can confirm it?

Comment: Okay, but it's not pretty, especially after modifying it for the two toes limit. Let me put a little lipstick (comments) on it first.

Answer (score 0):

Per your request, here is the program I made. It was done in Visual Basic for Excel. Below is a screenshot of Excel after the macro executed:

[image]

For the program to work, it is necessary that the "toe values" in row 3 are entered into Excel beforehand, exactly as shown. The X's below the toe values show which toes were chosen for each sum. To count the number of sums created or the number of ambiguous sums, insert a filter at row 3. The screenshot can be enlarged by clicking on it.

Below are screenshots showing the program:

[image]
[image]

The program takes about 20 seconds to run.